# How to query a Mongo with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongodb-query

I realize this sounds like a completely redundant question, but just hear me out.

Eventually I'd like to query MongoDB from the dom, but until then I'm okay with doing from my routes module. Here is my query:

```
var db = require('./config/db.js');

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.jsonp(db.getData('sampleSet'));
});
```

'sampleSet' is the name of the collection I'm querying. The getData function is supposed to get data from MongoDB. I'm putting it in the callback of MongoClient's connect function because I can't figure any other way. From my point of view, since `getData()` is returning a function with a callback, `findData`, it should return the data. But it doesn't. The console.logs return the data, but it must be returning undefined.

```
function findData (db, c, callback) {
  var collection = db.collection(c);
  collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);   
    callback(docs);
  });
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(err, null);
  console.log('CONNECTED CORRECTLY TO SERVER.');
  exports.getData = function(c) {
    return 
    findData(db, c, function(docs) {
      console.log('FOUND THE FOLLOWING RECORDS: ');
      return docs;
      db.close();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: `res.jsonp` will end up using the return value of the `getData` call (which is nothing)

Answer (score 5):

If `var db = require('./config/db.js');` is your schema, and `'sampleSet'` is collection name , Then you can get the data using this

```js
router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  db.sampleSet.find({},function(err,data){
    if(err)
      throw err;
    else
      res.send(data)
    });
  });
```

but for this you have to write your `db.js` file in this way

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;



var sampleSetSchema = new Schema({
//Your schemas goes here..
  // fields : types
  // ..
  // ..
}, {
 collection: "sampleSet" // collection name
});



// // Export the Mongoose model

var SampleSet = mongoose.model('SampleSet', sampleSetSchema);
module.exports = {

 SampleSet: SampleSet

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `findData` method is not returning anything.

It is passing `docs` to `callback` and `callback` is returning `docs` again to `findData` method. But there is no return from `findData`.

So if `findData` is not returning anything, `getData` is not going to return anything.